# Explaining SMART power error

Tags: hard-disk, smart

I use `gsmartcontrol`, on the Error tab, it shows:

```
Complete error log:

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 398 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 398 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 125 hours (5 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 01 0f 08 00 00  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x0000080f = 2063

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 10 00 00 08 00 40 00      00:09:15.084  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:09:15.006  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 10 03 00 00 00 00 00      00:09:14.990  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 00 00      00:09:14.974  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  b1 c1 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:09:14.959  DEVICE CONFIGURATION FREEZE LOCK [OBS-ACS-3]

Error 397 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 125 hours (5 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 01 0f 08 00 00  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x0000080f = 2063

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 10 00 00 08 00 40 00      00:09:14.756  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:09:14.678  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 10 03 00 00 00 00 00      00:09:14.662  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 00 00      00:09:14.646  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  b1 c1 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:09:14.631  DEVICE CONFIGURATION FREEZE LOCK [OBS-ACS-3]

Error 396 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 125 hours (5 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 01 0f 08 00 00  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x0000080f = 2063

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 10 00 00 08 00 40 00      00:09:14.508  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 02 00 00 40 00      00:09:14.506  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 04 00 07 00 00 40 00      00:09:14.506  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 00 00 40 00      00:09:14.506  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 00 00 40 00      00:09:14.506  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 395 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 125 hours (5 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 01 0f 88 b9 0a  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x0ab9880f = 179931151

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 10 00 00 88 b9 40 00      00:00:15.234  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:00:15.156  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 10 03 00 00 00 00 00      00:00:15.141  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 00 00      00:00:15.125  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  b1 c1 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:00:15.109  DEVICE CONFIGURATION FREEZE LOCK [OBS-ACS-3]

Error 394 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 125 hours (5 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 01 57 d1 54 08  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x0854d157 = 139776343

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 00 50 d1 54 40 00      00:00:14.984  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:00:14.922  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 10 03 00 00 00 00 00      00:00:14.906  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 00 00      00:00:14.891  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  b1 c1 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:00:14.875  DEVICE CONFIGURATION FREEZE LOCK [OBS-ACS-3]
```

[image: smart attributes]

what does this mean? and how to prevent that errors?

Answer (score 2):

"ICRC error" means that [data was corrupted during the transfer](http://ww2.cs.fsu.edu/~rosentha/linux/2.6.26.5/docs/DocBook/libata/ch07.html); given the age of your drive, the most likely cause is a bad cable. All told the possible causes seem to be:

- a bad cable (try re-seating your cable, and changing it if that doesn't fix things);
- a bad chipset (unlikely if your motherboard isn't very old);
- a bad drive.

If you get to the last stage, try the drive in another system to make sure... If it is the drive you shouldn't have any trouble getting it replaced.

Comment: The CRC is computed before it hits main memory so it can't be that.

Comment: I thought it was a CRC covering the data transferred using UDMA, not the data transferred to and from the drive (well, not only); so if there are non-reproducible reads from memory you might end up with a bit flipping between the time it was read for the transfer and read for the CRC (if the two reads are separate)... It may well be far-fetched though!

Comment: The CRC is applied by the drive or controller to the data as they transmit it, so memory is only read once.  If a bit is flipped in ram, then the controller transmits the flipped bit and computes a correct CRC on that bad data, which the drive can then verify.  They only know/care whether the data got corrupted as it traversed the sata cable, not whether it was bad when it was handed to them, or if it goes bad after the controller hands it to the computer.